# Ionic 4 running app on iOS device error with capacitor

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic4, capacitor

I have an ionic 4 project with capacitor. I tried to open and build an iOS version.
The Xcode successfully build and install the app.
But when the app is running it freezes at splash screen and I get this error on Xcode log:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/App
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: code signature in (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: code signature in (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: code signature in (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F39FC29D-255C-4BED-B6D5-6FEF4979C5F5/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: stat() failed with errno=1
```

I already check the automatic signing in the capabilities section to allow Xcode to do all necessary signing operations.
But all solution is not working for me and I get this message always.
My Xcode version is 10.2.1 and I have to mention that app is correctly running on Xcode iOS simulators.

Please help me, It's 2 days that I'm struggling with this error!

Thanks

Comment: Try changing your bundle identifier and certificate

Comment: @AaronJordan, This is not working!, And also I check automatically signing to let Xcode handle all requirements but I even test with manually select certificate and provision profile but nothing changed.

Comment: @Hanif Have you found a solution for this now?  I have had the same problem for a few days.  thank you in advance!

Comment: @programmers, unfortunately no!!

Answer (score 0):

you're using Free Developer Account ?

As many of us, you're probably using a package that now require a paid Apple developer account.

I have the same error ("code signature invalid") using Capacitor.

You can try to remove **use_frameworks!** and adding **use_modular_headers!** in your Podfile, but success will depend on the package your using. With capacitor it's not working.

There are many issues on github like this one: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8294

If you subscribe to paid account, it will work...

Waiting for news/updates by apple group of idiots people !